# Custom view isn't being restored after adding it to a layout from AsyncTask's onPostExecute()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I've written a pretty large custom view which overrides `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)`.

I wanted to populate a LinearLayout with my custom view, so I wrote the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout    mRootLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);

        int i;

        // Test: adding 10 instances of MyCustomView.
        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            MyCustomView cv = new MyCustomView(this);

            // I set an ID for this view so that onSaveInstanceState() and
            // onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) will be called
            // automatically.
            cv.setId(++i);

            mRootLayout.addView(cv);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

It works fine - `mRootLayout` is indeed being populated with 10 instances of `MyCustomView`, and each instance of `MyCustomView` is being properly restored after, for example, screen rotation.

I've noticed that due to the fact that `MyCustomView` is pretty large, my code is being heavy on the UI thread.

To solve the issue and take some effort off of the UI thread, I decided to use a custom AsyncTask, which will create an instance of `MyCustomView` in `doInBackground()` and add it to the the main layout ( `mRootLayout` ) in `onPostExecute()`.

The following code is my custom AsyncTask:

```
private class LoadMyCustomViewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MyCustomView> {

    private Context         mContext;
    private LinearLayout    mLayoutToPopulate;
    private int             mId;

    public LoadMyCustomViewTask(Context context, LinearLayout layout, int id) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutToPopulate = layout;
        mId = id;
    }

    @Override
    protected MyCustomView doInBackground(Void... params) {

        MyCustomView cv = new MyCustomView(mContext);

        return cv;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(MyCustomView result) {

        result.setId(mId);
        mLayoutToPopulate.addView(result);
    }
}
```

In `MainActivity` I use it as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout    mRootLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);

        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {

            new LoadMyCustomViewTask(this, mRootLayout, ++i).execute();
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

This code works too, but there is only one problem - `MyCustomView` is not being restored at all.

For debug purposes I put a Log.d(...) in `MyCustomView`'s `onSaveInstanceState()` and in `onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)`, and I've noticed that `onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)` **isn't being called**.

Do you have any idea why `onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)` isn't being called when I use an AsyncTask to populate `mRootLayout`, but it is indeed being called when I create `MyCustomView` **completely** on the UI thread?

Thank you.

**Edit: I'm posting the methods `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` of `MyCustomView`**

```
@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    debug("onSaveInstanceState()");
    Bundle state = new Bundle();
    state.putParcelable(_BUNDLE_KEY_PARENT_STATE, super.onSaveInstanceState());
    state.putBooleanArray(_BUNDLE_KEY_CLICKED_VIEWS, mClickedViews);
    return state;
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    debug("onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)");
    if (state instanceof Bundle) {
        Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
        mClickedViews = bundle.getBooleanArray(_BUNDLE_KEY_CLICKED_VIEWS);
        state = bundle.getParcelable(_BUNDLE_KEY_PARENT_STATE);
    }

    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View state restoration begins at the root view and moves down to all of the child views attached at that time. This can be seen in the [ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState%28android.util.SparseArray%29) method. This means that Android can only restore your views if they are part of the view hierarchy at the time `Activity.onRestoreInstanceState` is called.

Using the `AsyncTask`, you are creating your views asynchronously and then scheduling them to be added some time later when the main looper is idle. Considering the lifecycle, Android only lets your `AsyncTask.onPostExecute` run after `Activity.onStart`, `Activity.onRestoreInstanceState`, `Activity.onResume`, etc. are called. Your views are being added to the layout too late for automatic restoration to take place.

If you add log statements to those methods mentioned above, as well as to your `AsyncTask.onPostExecute`, you will be able to see how the ordering/timing plays out in reality. The following code runs after `Activity.onRestoreInstanceState` even though it all happens on the main thread, simply because of the scheduling:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("TAG", "when does this run?");
        }
    });

    ...
}
```

Comment: @nylon100 please reward the bounty if it was helpful :)

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I thought you'll be rewarded after I accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Smells like a false observation... creating a view on a background thread should not affect your activity lifecycle.

That said, doing anything at all with View objects on background threads is a no-no and I'm surprised you got this far with such an approach. All View code should be quick and avoid blocking. If you have long-running work to do then separate that work into the background thread, post the results of that complex computation to the main thread, and keep all the actual View/presentation stuff on the main thread where it belongs.

Comment: Hello Reuben and thank you for answering. Creating a thousand+ instances of MyCustomView is a long-running work which I decided to split into two tasks - creation and presentation. The creation of MyCustomView is being done in a separate thread, since that is the bigger task. The task is being performed in `onPostExectue()`, since it must be done in the UI thread. MyCustomView gets an instance of MainActivity which is responsible of holding that view and showing it to the user. Actually I don't see where is the problem. Can you please elaborate - why is that a "no-no" ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say: "The *presentation* task is being performed in `onPostExecute()`..."

Comment: Unless you're actually displaying 1000 views simultaneously, which seems unlikely, you don't need to create that many. Maybe you should describe the app and the purpose of the custom view in a bit more detail and better approaches could be suggested. As to the 'no-no', views should only ever be accessed / updated by the main thread because this is Android's way of ensuring the UI is consistent without every method on every view requiring synchronization locking (which would be very expensive and slow things down a lot). In other words UI is faster and better if only one thread is responsible.

Comment: `MyCustomView` is a tiny block in a larger application that I currently develop. Giving more details about its function will miss the point and will just make you confused. I can be more specific though and say that it is a 6X10 button matrix with a pretty complex embedded functionality. I actually solved the problem using a custom adapter which populates a simple list view. The problem that I've presented here remains, since I don't really understand why is that happening. Is there a hidden part which I miss, in the creation itself of `MyCustomView` when created in a separate thread?

Answer (score 0):

I remember having read about how `onSaveInstanceState()/onRestoreInstanceState()` work a time ago and it was not a "fixed-situation-rules" thing. As I can't find the references to it at this moment, I'll try to explain it with my own words:

Basically, a factor on which depends the calling of those methods is the resources left that the device has. Both methods will get in action when a second `Activity` gets focused and the first one gets killed due to lack of resources. Concretely, `onRestoreInstanceState` should be triggered when that `Activity` was killed and restarted, so it gets the previous state.

Although you've not posted your `MyCustomView` implementation, my guess is that when you do that entirely on the main UI Thread, you're involving some action that makes the `MainActivity` lose its focus and once the `MyCustomView` is created, it needs to restore its state. Doing this in a separate thread (as `AsyncTask` does) makes creating those `View`s in paralell, so your main `Activity` doesn't lose its focus and thus it doesn't get killed, so those methods are not called.

Concluding this, don't worry if those methods are not always called as they don't have to be called **everytime**, just when needed, and that doesn't mean there's something going wrong.

Comment: Hello NKN, and thank you for answering. I updated the code to include `MyCustomView`'s `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`. I want to mention again that they work fine together and that the problem is only when `MyCustomView` is being created in a background thread ( yet, it is *added* in `onPostExecute()` as it must be). Your answer is interesting, but I'm looking for that _specific_ action that is being involved while `MyCustomView` is being created not entirely in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to connect SDK sources to your IDE and walk there with debugger through the whole process related with the `View` class `onRestoreInstanceState()`. Since I don't have your code, looking at sources I can only guess what might have gone wrong, but from what I see, that might be related to problem:

1) try to set an Id to every view you generate

2) try to use `Fragment` as a host to your views (instead of `MainActivity`).

Comment: Hello Dmide. I already tried both. An id was set to each child and `MainActivity` was replaced by `ListFragment`, but the problem remains. Yes, I will go through it with a debugger. Thank you.